# Парсинг JSON в xcode, словарь в массиве

Tags: xcode, json, ios, objective-c, синтаксический-анализ

Не нашел уроков на Русском, а 50% уроков на старые iOS (нереально много кода).

Напишите компактный, работающий парсинг JSON.
Допустим я имею:

> ```
> {
> "sms":
> [{
> "phone": "79641234567",
> "message": "Что делаешь",
> "to_phone": "79121234567",
> "sent": "06.06.2014 11:56:51"
> },
> {
> "phone": "79641234567",
> "message": "Как дела",
> "to_phone": "79121234567",
> "sent": "06.06.2014 11:56:41"
> }]
> }
> ```

Допустим нужно выдернуть из массива "sms", все "phone".

*Запрос в гугле частый, но способы старые, не через nsjsonserialization, думаю будет полезно для всех, кто зашел сюда через поиск.*

Comment: Уже, просто оба небыли верны, а вот у Bimawa оказался рабочий, за что ему спасибо. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSData *responseData = [@"{\n"
                            "\"sms\":\n"
                            "[{\n"
                            "\"phone\": \"79641234567\",\n"
                            "\"message\": \"Что делаешь\",\n"
                            "\"to_phone\": \"79121234567\",\n"
                            "\"sent\": \"06.06.2014 11:56:51\"\n"
                            "},\n"
                            "{\n"
                            "\"phone\": \"79641234567\",\n"
                            "\"message\": \"Как дела\",\n"
                            "\"to_phone\": \"79121234567\",\n"
                            "\"sent\": \"06.06.2014 11:56:41\"\n"
                            "}]\n"
                            "}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *responseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:responseDic])
    {
        NSArray *array = [responseDic objectForKey:@"sms"];
        NSMutableArray *phones = [NSMutableArray new];
        [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [phones addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"phone"]];
        }];

        NSLog(@"%@", phones);

    }
```

Comment: У вас единственный рабочий способ, спасибо. (только в NSData url, но роли особо не играет.)

Answer (score 1):

Лукавите, ой лукавите - примеров тьма))

Можно так:

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)jsonRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url
{
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSMutableDictionary *allElements = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    return allElements;
}
```

Расписываю - ну, уж не знаю, как еще проще объяснить, мне казалось, что не составит труда перебрать массив:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dicJS = [JSONParse jsonRequestWithURL:JSON_URL];
DLog(@"%@", dicJS);

NSMutableArray *phoneArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *dictTemp in [dicJS objectForKey:@"sms"])
{           
    [phoneArray addObject:[dictTemp objectForKey:@"phone"]];            
}
DLog(@"%@", dicJS);
```

Comment: Ну не правда) Скоро еще вопросы по swift'у будут)

Comment: Ну вообщем этот способ так же как и другие (о которых вы говорите), не открывают массив [], allElements выбивает - null. Как быть? Я находил подобные проблемы, но решения толкового так и не было.

Comment: @Melio, ну серьезно - вы хоть пытались разбираться?? А то складывается впечатление, что просто ждали пока ПОЛНОСТЬЮ до строчки распишут вам?? Это ж несерьезно)) имхо)
Матчасть, матчасть...))

Answer (score 1):

А чем `NSJSONSerialization` не угодил?

```
NSJSONSerialization *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves 
                                             error:&error];

NSMutableArray phonesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (error == nil) {
    for (NSDictionary *i in [json valueForKey:@"sms"]) {
        [phonesArray addObject:[[i valueForKey:@"phone"] stringValue]];
    }
}
```

Comment: NSArray *phonesArray? 
"[phonesArray addObject" - не дает addObject

Comment: Не предирайтесь - хороший ответ. Очевидно же, что NSMutableArray.

Comment: @Melio, пардон, действительно глупая ошибка =)

Comment: Второй NSArray тоже измените, а то введете в заблуждение ученика :D.

Этот способ выбивает error, как я понимаю, он не открывают массив [] (как и способ выше). Как быть?

Comment: А ошибка-то какая?

Comment: @eulers_child, вот и я о том же))